# Nullable- это больше, чем структура?

Tags: c#, .net

В общем, интереса ради залез в исходники [`Nullable<T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,e870b169310b6d83) и увидел вот такое:

```
public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T value) {
    return new Nullable<T>(value);
}
internal T value;

    public Nullable(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.hasValue = true;
    }
```

Я же правильно понимаю, что CLR сама как-то особенно работает с этим типом?
Так как иначе я не понимаю, как оно работает в этом случае:

```
float? nullabe=null
```

По логике null должен передастся в конструктор и пристроится типу T, который из себя представляет значимый тип => падение.

Comment: А откуда уверенность, что вызовется этот конструктор?

Comment: @yolosora там там, вроде, только 1 конструктор.

Comment: У всех структур есть конструктор без параметров

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да, но неявное преобразование ведь переопределено. Разве он может быть вызван в этом случае?

Comment: Но в любом случае магия в Nullable есть, но мне кажется, она не в CLR, а в компиляторе языка

Comment: Там же есть комментарий: `Warning, don't put System.Runtime.Serialization.On*Serializ*Attribute
on this class without first fixing ObjectClone::InvokeVtsCallbacks
Also, because we have special type system support that says a a boxed Nullable<T>
can be used where a boxed<T> is use, Nullable<T> can not implement any intefaces
at all (since T may not).   Do NOT add any interfaces to Nullable!
` Который как по мне объясняет это дело.

Comment: Ну с помощью магии компилятора здесь как раз и будет вызван конструктор без параметров, я думаю.

Comment: Неявное преобразование из T, но null это не T

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В данном случае, CLR тут ни при чём, это компилятор видит что ожидается тип `Nullable<float>` и сам подставляет  default-значение вместо null. И особое поведение операторов `is/as` точно так же реализуется компилятором.

Однако, `Nullable<>` - и правда особенный для CLR тип. Его особенностью является тот факт, что вы никогда не увидите его упакованную версию:

```cs
int? i = 5;
object o = i;
Console.WriteLine(o.GetType()); // System.Int32
int j = (int)o; // работает
```